# toggleclass con React JS que afecta al elemento que le precede

Tags: html5, reactjs

estoy intentando hacer un tipo toggleclass de jQuery a reactJs
tengo este ejemplo, pero le cambia a la clase a las 2 y yo solo quiero que se la cambie el div que le precede, lo que quiero hacer es como en jQuery seria
`funtion toggleMenu(){$(this).next().toggleclass('show');}`
y lo que quiero evitar es repetir codigo para hacer un click para cada menu

---

```
class Gen extends React.Component{
    state = { showMenu: false }

    toggleMenu = () => {
        this.setState({
            showMenu: !this.state.showMenu
        })
    }
    render(){
        const menuVis = this.state.showMenu ? 'show' : 'hide';
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
                        //contenido
                    </div>
                    <div className={`menu ${menuVis}`}>
                        //contenido
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div onClick={this.toggleMenu}>
                        //contenido
                    </div>
                    <div className={`menu ${menuVis}`}>
                        //contenido
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

---

aparte que quisiera que no estuviera dentro de la clase para hacer la funcion toggleMenu reutilizable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que podrias hacer para que cada div sea "independiente" es crear un componente que maneje su propio estado, algo asi:

```
class ToggleComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    active: false
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      active: !this.state.active
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.state.active ? "nombredeLaClase" : ""}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.props.texto}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Y usarias el componente asi:

```
  <div>
    <ToggleComponent texto="text 1" />
    <ToggleComponent texto="texto 2" />
  </div>
```

Claro, en ejemplo que hice use un boton, pero es la idea, que tengas un componente que maneje su propio estado.